# EmberJS Data DS.JSONSerializer vs. DS.JSONAPISerializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a EmberJS project with two Model, they both seams to use different serializers. By debugging inside EmberJS Data i've seen that for the first Model the class of Serializer is "DS.JSONAPISerializer" and for the other "DS.JSONSerializer". I would like they both use the same.

I didn't override any serializers and their respective adapters are empty and extend the same adapter (GeneralAdapter).

The only difference is that ModelA objects are pushed to Ember from the server using a request and the adapter (using the same adapter as ModelB) whereas ModelB is only pushing from store.pushPayload from a controller (without using the adapter).

Is it a feature or a bug or I totally miss understanding something?

EDIT:

Adapter code:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend(DS.BuildURLMixin, {
    namespace: rabbit.common.baseUrl + 'editor-jersey',

    defaultSerializer: '-rest',

    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json'
    },

    findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken) {
        var adapter = this;
        var url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, null, 'findAll');

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
                Ember.run(null, resolve, data[type.modelName + "s"]);
            }.bind(this), function(jqXHR) {
                jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
                Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this));  
    },

    findRecord: function(store, type, id, snapshot) {
        var url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'findRecord');

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                Ember.run(null, resolve, data[type.modelName]);
            }, function(jqXHR) {
                jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
                Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
            });
        });
    },

    updateRecord: function(store, type, snapshot) {
        var adapter = this;
        var data = this.serialize(snapshot, { includeId: true });

        var url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, snapshot.id, snapshot, 'updateRecord');

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).then(function(data) {
                Ember.run(null, resolve, data[type.modelName]);
            }, function(jqXHR) {
                jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
                Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
            });
        });
    },

    createRecord: function(store, type, snapshot) {
        var adapter = this;
        var data = this.serialize(snapshot, { includeId: true });

        var url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, snapshot, 'createRecord');

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).then(function(data) {
                if (snapshot.isNew) {
                    data[type.modelName].isNew = snapshot.isNew;
                }
                Ember.run(null, resolve, data[type.modelName]);
            }, function(jqXHR) {
                jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
                Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It might be a couple things. `JSONAPISerializer` extends `JSONSerializer` so if you're diving deeper into the stack you will end up in the latter. Can you share the request+pushPayload code? And versions. If you're using Ember Data 2.x the default should be `JSONAPIAdapter`/`JSONAPISerializer`.

Comment: I'm using ` headers: {
  accept: 'application/json'
 }` in the adapter. Do you think this is the reason why JSONSerializer is used?

Comment: I added the code of the adapter. I'm now using `defaultAdapter` to set it to the rest one.

Comment: You should be doing `DS.RESTAdapter.extend` instead, if that's the one you wish to use. `DS.Adapter` is the base class for all the (core) adapters, and `DS.Serializer` for all serializers.